# Is there I can do to make this concrete front yard look better/less damaged?

Tags: concrete, fence, paving

many thanks in advance for any help.

I am house sitting for my elderly mother for 2 weeks whilst she is away. I have been doing lots of yard work to try and make it more habitable for her as a surprise.

Her front garden looked very muddy and overgrown with algae. After power washing I realised that actually the front garden concrete is very broken/incomplete and jagged with soil poking through.

Is there anything I can do cheaply/easily to level the surface of the concrete? I don't need a perfect fix but just something less ugly and safer to walk on.

Many thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: No, not really. Patch work and paint will look nice, but only for a year or two, before it breaks apart and peels up. Just patching big holes will make it safer in the short term. If safety is the only concern, I'd remove it completely, prep the soil, then do pavers. That's *cheaper*, but not cheap.

Comment: thank you for this comment! how could i patch it up in the short term do you think? it looks like aggregate concrete to me, i'm not sure if you know anything about patching that up? ideally, i would do a short term fix and then save for a proper replacement later.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not much you can do that will last long enough to really be worth it. Patch work and paint will look nice, but only for a year or two at most, before it breaks apart and peels up. Just patching big holes will make it safer in the short term, but it also will not last.

By "patching" I mean mixing some concrete and putting it in the holes. I wouldn't bother with anything less than a half inch because the patch will fracture and pull up in only a few weeks. You can buy small "patching" bags, but a standard bag is pretty cheap already (less than $10), but really heavy, usually coming in 60lbs or 80lbs bags. Concrete is really easy to mix. Just add water, stir, and repeat until you get a thick waffle-batter consistency. If it's too loose, just add more mix. Then use a trowel to scoop it into the holes, then smooth it out and stay off it for a full day. Check your weather report for rain and cold under 50F before you start.

If safety is the only concern, I'd  eventually remove it completely, prep the soil, then do pavers. That's *cheaper* than new concrete, but not cheap.